# How to have a Universal autosuggestion for any code entered once in any zsh terminal

Tags: command-line, zsh, tmux

Suppose I type a set of commands in a particular pane of Tmux. The autosuggestion feature of Tmux recognizes and helps in that pane (terminal).

Let me say I started a new pane. The autosuggestion codes of the previous pane are not working in the new terminal.

**How to have a universal autosuggestion for any codes entered once in zsh terminal?**